# How to exclude files from outside my workspace from ESLint in VSCode?

Tags: eslint, lint

When I'm in a workspace and open an external file (from outside of workspace) in VSCode, how can I exclude this file from lint? More specifically from pug-lint but the same applies to ESLint?

The thing is that I want to exclude all files from outside my project (workspace), as in: if `./` is my project root folder, I want to exclude everything out of this (`.././`). This happens if I'm working in a project and open some file from outside that project, and ESLint starts working on it and messaging me about lint errors...I would like to avoid this clutter.